# Google Sheets: Internal Error Executing Custom Function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am creating a custom function in Google Spreadsheet's script editor, let me present the code first:

```
function customFunction(input_array) {
var sorted = input_array.slice().sort(function(a,b){return a-b})

bins = []
var initial = sorted[0]
var final = sorted[sorted.length - 1]

while (initial < final) {
    initial += 0.03
    bins.push(initial)
    }

return bins

}
```

So basically, the variables "initial" and "final" are the problematic ones. Because if I change these variables to specific numbers, instead of the array index that I have here, the function works.

How do I resolve this for implementation in Google Sheets?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this script your latest one? Because ``bin`` of the returned value is not declared in the function ``customFunction()``. How about this?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post. The script I was working on was returning "bins" not "bin". Thanks!

Comment: I would perhaps check your value for `final`. Make sure it's not being returned as a string

Comment: @ScottMcC Yep, I did. I tried returning both "initial" and "final" variable without implementing the while loop yet and yes, I am getting integer values for each. This is expected since the array named "sorted" contains elements that are integers.

Comment: @HQuizzagan Do you still have the problem?

Comment: @HQuizzagan What happens when you only set `final` to a value such as `1.03`?

Comment: @JSmith yep, the problem still exists.

Comment: @ScottMcC If I "hard-code" the variable "final = to any float/integer" it won't still work unless the variable "initial" is also hard coded.

So basically, the error cannot recognize the referencing for the value of both variables "initial" and "final". So weird!!

Google sheets can't seem to recognize it.

Comment: Try parseInt(sorted[0]) and parseInt(sorted[sorted.length - 1]) and see if that helps?

Comment: Why declare `bins` as a global? Declare it locally `var bins =[]` Also, What's your input array? No matter how you get the array, it's always a 2D array- You use it as if it's 1D. Although there's implicit type conversion in certain cases, You'd need to call values as it is `var initial =sorted[0][0]`

Comment: @JPV Yep I also tried converting the reference output to integer. Aside from the fact that output of the "sorted[0]" is already integer (since the sorted array is only composed of float elements - the data was already cleaned), this was still being recognized by google sheets as reference cannot be determined.

Comment: @TheMaster Why declare it locally? I am defining an array whose elements are appended every time the while loop under it gets executed.

Also, the input array is 1D. Array is not always 2D. My input_array is literally just one column, multiple rows [1xn] matrix. So the referencing I think is still correct.

Comment: When you declare globally, you're declaring globally- `bins` can be accessed from any file and will have multiple conflicts. It should be declared locally. And array is always 2D. A1:A3 looks like this:`[[A1],[A2],[A3]]` where A1's value is ``array[0][0]``. Also use `;` at the end of each statement. Try and see.